# How can i get my emgu function to work on x86?

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bit, emgucv

I made a c# project with emgu CV in x64. It does a template-match. However I now realize i need it to work on x86 systems. When i change this in the build settings i get this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
Additional information: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.

I break it and the problem is with this line:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> template = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imagetofind);
```

I have no idea why. (it works perfectly on x64).

P.S i have all dll's set up correctly for x64, do i need to replace them with x86 dll's?

Answer (score 1):

> P.S i have all dll's set up correctly for x64, do i need to replace them with x86 dll's?

Yes, you do. The dll architecture has to match the application architecture. I had the exact same error because I thought I was using x64, and copied x64 dll's. However,, the application was actually x86. I fixed that by making the application x64.

So either make a x64 application to use with the x64 dll's, or use the x86 dll's.

See also here: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.